# Gnuplot, setting yrange days back

Tags: gnuplot

I have put up a raspberry pi to measure temperature and call a Gnuplot script to place a graph on a webpage.

Now i want to make a couple of graphs that display 1hour backwards in time/1day backwards in time.

Does anyone know how i specify the X-range to start at "current time - 1 day" or "current time - 1 hour"?

Thanx!

Comment: I actually think that this is an interesting question.  However, in order for it to be really useful, it would help to show what your input datafile looks like (just a few points is fine) and what your attempt at a gnuplot script looks like.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work everywhere, but if your gnuplot supports pipes and your system has the `date` command ...

```
TIMEFMT = "%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S"
#now = "`date +%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S`"  #Use this line in production
now = '2013:01:24:20:49:30'  #Hard-code this for the sake of the example ...
now_secs = strptime(TIMEFMT,now)
one_hour_past = now_secs - 3600.0

set xdata time
#set timefmt TIMEFMT  #This doesn't parse correctly ... Not sure why...
eval(sprintf('set timefmt "%s"',TIMEFMT))

print strftime(TIMEFMT,one_hour_past)

#set xrange [strftime(TIMEFMT,one_hour_past):]  #This doesn't seem to work
#set xrange ["2013:01:24:20:49:30":]            #This works, but is declared statically -- Yuck.
eval(sprintf('set xrange ["%s":]',strftime(TIMEFMT,one_hour_past)))

plot '-' u 1:2 w l
   2013:01:24:10:00:00 2.5
   2013:01:24:21:00:00 2
   2013:01:24:22:00:00 3
   e
```

Answer (score 0):

THe code i have used is as follows. Im running it on a Raspberry Pi with Rasbian OS. Any sudgestions? Thanx!

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
reset
set terminal png size 1250,700
set object 1 rectangle from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1 fillcolor rgb"#E6E6FA" behind

set output '/var/www/bild.png'
set multiplot

set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set format x "%H:%M\n%d/%m"
set xlabel "Timme/datum"

set ylabel "Inomhustemperatur"
set yrange [15:28]

set y2label "Utomhustemperatur"
set y2range [-20:10]
set y2tics nomirror
set y2tics

set title "Temperatur"
set key reverse Left outside
set grid

set style data lines

plot "logg.txt" using 1:3 axes x1y1 lw 3 title "inomhus", "" using 1:4 axes x1y2 lw 3   title "utomhus"#
```